# customizing serialized object in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a response for an api,

```
 "mailinglist": [
        {
            "id": 690,
            "name": "Donotdelete",
            "count": "3",
            "mailing_list": 109,
            "person": [
                {
                    "id": 939,
                    "first_name": "Aladdin",
                    "last_name": "Abdul",
                    "email": "aladdin@sharklasers.com",
                    "mailinglist_id": 109
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 691,
            "name": "Donotdelete",
            "count": "3",
            "mailing_list": 109,
            "person": [
                {
                    "id": 938,
                    "first_name": "smitha",
                    "last_name": "sraj",
                    "email": "smithasraj.kp@gmail.com",
                    "mailinglist_id": 109
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

using nested serializer method.but i have to change this response to

```
"mailinglist": [
        {
            "id": 690,
            "name": "Donotdelete",
            "count": "3",
            "mailing_list": 109,
            "person": [
                {
                    "id": 938,
                "first_name": "smitha",
                "last_name": "sraj",
                "email": "smithasraj.kp@gmail.com",
                "mailinglist_id": 109
                },{
                    "id": 939,
                    "first_name": "smitha",
                    "last_name": "sraj",
                    "email": "smithasraj.kp@gmail.com",
                    "mailinglist_id": 109
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

the common fields like name count mailing list should be outside the array.Is there any option to do this? Can we iterate the serializer data object and can be customize it?

Comment: I can't see the difference you're making here. Name, count and mailing_list are in the same place in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can override `to_representation()` method of each serializer.

Each serializer has a `to_representation()` which will create json data for response. you can add any item that you want in it or pop anything that is not in the right place. for example:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

     def to_representation(self, instance):
         r = super().to_representation(instance)
         r.update({'test': 'value of test'}
         return r
```